# key restriction jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to create my first jQuery plugin which should provide methods for input restriction. Here is the code. But I don't know how to pass parameter "event" for keydown event.

```
(function ($) {
var methods = {
    IntegerOnly: function (event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
};

$.fn.inputRestriction = function (method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.inputRestriction');
    }   
};
})(jQuery);
```

It should be called like

```
$('#txtInteger').inputRestriction('IntegerOnly');
```

Comment: How is this plugin supposed to be used? You're not binding an event handler, is the application supposed to call this within their own `keydown` handler?

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written the plugin, it must be used this way:

```
$("txtInteger").keydown(function(event) {
    $(this).inputRestriction('IntegerOnly', event);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I think the way I have written plugin is definitely not a good way. Can you tell me what would be the correct way of restricting character via plugin.

Comment: What you probably want your plugin to do is add its own `keydown` handler to the element it's run on. I'm not experienced at writing plugins, so I'm not going to try to show that in detail. Look at how plugins like validate and autocomplete bind handlers.